# How do I use a feature flag?

Tags: juju

I am trying to use the VSphere provider but I am being told "It's behind a feature flag", how do I use a feature flag with Juju?

Comment: Update: [VMware vSphere](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere.html) is no longer behind a feature flag: https://docs.jujucharms.com/2.4/en/help-vmware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `JUJU_DEV_FEATURE_FLAGS` variable to whatever feature you are trying to enable. You do this when you bootstrap.

```
JUJU_DEV_FEATURE_FLAGS=vsphere-provider juju bootstrap controllername cloudname
```